# MS SQL server management studio 2008 r2 not working with MS windows 7 users

Tags: sql-server

I am running windows 7 professional and have used MS SQL server management studio many times without any incidents by running it using an Admin user name. In my current installation, another windows user can open up MSSQL server management studio, but cannot open/create any databases. I tried giving that windows user all the administrator access, but it hasn't helped.

Comment: Have you seen any errors or messages? Did you create Login for this user on the server? Security->Right Click on Logins->New Login. And then create User for that Login in the Database.

Answer (score 0):

While logged in as the user that you think should have permissions, execute the following:

```
DECLARE @a sysname = SUSER_SNAME()
EXEC xp_logininfo @acctname = @a, @option = 'all'
```

In the result set, if none of the rows have 'admin' in the privilege column, then the user doesn't have administrative rights.  You can fix this by executing:

```
exec sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = 'your login here', @rolename = 'sysadmin'
```